# Selfsize grid item in SwiftUI

Tags: layout, grid, swiftui, sizing

I have used `adaptive` and `flexible` with `minimum` size with no luck.

```
struct ContentView: View {

    let rows = [
        GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: 80)) // lowering this cuases an unwanted shrink of text.
    ]

    var body: some View {
        LazyVGrid(columns: rows, spacing: 8) {
            ForEach((0...10), id: \.self) { item in
                Text("\(Int.random(in: 0...50000))")
                    .background(Color.yellow)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

## Result:

[image: Result]

As you can see, seems like it takes the `minimum` size as a `fixed` size instead! Also, note that I don't know the minimum size since `Text` is self-sizing.

How can we have a self-sizing item for `LazyVGrid` or `LazyHGrid`?

<sub>I wanted it to look like a tag view.</sub>

Comment: You mean that you wanted it to look like a tag cloud (so every number is a tag and they are getting laid out like in `UICollectionView` + flow layout)?

Comment: Yep. Each one should have it own width based on it's content. Looks like all grid items are same in size.

Comment: Did you try that already https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59129890/implementing-a-tag-list-in-swiftui?

Comment: That's using `Stack`s, not `Grid`

Comment: Yes, and I think stacks are more suitable for what you want to achieve. Isn’t it?

Comment: I **am** using `stack` in my project, but thats not the issue.

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini Trying the same right now. Were you able to find a solution using LazyVGrid in the meantime?